# Multidimensional array in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular

I'm confused a little about Arrays in Typescript ( Angular 2 )
I need a follow array to send to my API.

```
array = [
cadSocios => true,
name => ['name1', 'name2'],
part => ['part1', 'part2']
];
```

How Can I do this?

Comment: That's not array, that's an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Json.

```
array = {
"cadSocios" : true,
"name" : ['name1', 'name2'],
part : ['part1', 'part2']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your object representation in json array

```
array=[
  {'cadSocios': true, 'name': 'name_1', 'part': 'part_1' },
  {'cadSocios': true, 'name': 'name_2', 'part': 'part_2' },
  //...
  {'cadSocios': true, 'name': 'name_n', 'part': 'part_n' },
]
```